# Android application with Firebase crashes at startup

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-ndk

I use Android Studio 3.5.1 and develop my Android app in it. I need Firebase to provide user sign-in functionality. I configured everything according to Google's instruction. However my app crashes instantly on startup (before it even reaches activity's onCreate function). I've collected logs from my phone developer's options and here is what I found there:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

In case it matters my app is Android NDK app. I've subclassed NativeActivity with a small class just to investigate what's going on, and it works fine until I add Firebase.

Here are related snippets from my configuration:

Project-level build.gradle:

```
...
buildscript/dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
...
```

App-level build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    ...
}
...
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Also according to instruction I opened Firebase console, created a project and added Android application. I've set the same package name as I use in my project. In case it matters - the app is live on Google Play Store. Also I've generated SHA1 from my keystore as it was asked and saved it into my app in Firebase console. It gave me `google-services.json` that I put to `project/app/google-services.json`.

Still it keeps crashing. Googling on the error message from the log gives nothing helpful. I miss something but I can't figure out what and I'm lack of ideas. I can provide any additional information that can help. Stackoverflow, you're my last and the best hope :)

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Your error log says the strings your trying to pass are empty

Comment: The app crashes before it reaches any of my code - the next string in the call stack is "android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5200)" - it can't initialize (or install?) Firebase provider. As I understand it expects some String but gets a null (or an empty string). And this happens on some initial phase of the app launch. No client code is executed at this point. At least no code that I wrote by my hands in Android Studio :)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: OK, just assume it's pure NDK application and there is no Java code at all. Do you want to see my C++ code? :)